# Reading data from file in php

Tags: php

I am reading from a file like this :

```
while ($log = fgets(STDIN)) {
 //contained in file read.php
  print $log;
}
```

Where I use following command for STDIN of php file.

```
cat input.txt | php read.php
```

I am concerned about memory usage in the sense that does that code read input.txt line by line , so that net memory usage is per line read. Or is this the case that code will use memory corresponding to all the lines ?
i.e. if there are 10 lines, memory usage is corresponding to 10*memory usage of one line.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use STDIN? Why not pass the file name then use `fopen`?

Comment: You control how much memory the script uses through the amount of data you read from the file at once and how much you keep that data in memory. The posted code reads one line at a time, sends it to the output then reuses the buffer. Nothing to worry about as long as your file doesn't contain lines of zillions of characters.

Comment: @axiac I don't know that you're entirely correct. From the perspective of PHP, you're right, `fgets` is only going to read one line at a time from STDIN. `cat` though is a different story. I believe that cat will dump the entire file onto STDIN without waiting for php to read the next line. Even if that's not the case for `cat` other processes may not behave well. I think this method is at risk of spending a lot of memory on STDIN.

Comment: @KingIsaac you are right but it is not something that the PHP script could control. And instead of piping the output of `cat`, the OP could simply redirect the input of their script and the problem vanishes. Or pass the file name in the command line and handle the file opening in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This example is really simple to test! Just create script with code from question and run it against huge file. And I've did it! More over I'd reduced memory limit intentionally with purpose to receive fatal error - but no, it works! So my answer is - I believe this code works.